Ghost string in terminal, string doesn't go away when using backspace
Linux shell problem on a server, bash 5.1.4(1)-release. Debian 11.10.
I have this on my command line right now after pressing the up arrow:
server# ctr plugins listkubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --cri-socket=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock

(Note that this appears to be two commands, concatenated, back to back, without a space or newline between them)
However, if I hold in backspace, it only deletes up to this point:
server# ctr plugins list

If I try to do more backspace, it doesn't go further back. If I just hit enter, it is clear that there is actually nothing being sent to the shell. The string "ctr plugins list" is just a ghost string, if you will, which is not actually being sent to the shell.
I've tried to relogin and tried to "reset" the shell.
What is causing this? This is through SSH.
export:
declare -x HOME="/home/user"
declare -x JAVA_HOME="/opt/jre"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
declare -x LOGNAME="user"
declare -x LS_COLORS=""
declare -x MOTD_SHOWN="pam"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/jre/bin"
declare -x PS1="\\[\\033[1;33m\\]\\H\\033[0;35m\\]\\\$\\033[0;37m\\] "
declare -x PWD="/home/user"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_CLIENT="192.168.1.137 59546 22"
declare -x SSH_CONNECTION="192.168.1.137 59546 192.168.1.10 22"
declare -x SSH_TTY="/dev/pts/0"
declare -x TERM="alacritty"
declare -x USER="user"
declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_CLASS="user"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="27"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_TYPE="tty"


Your PS1 is broken. You need to quote the non-printing characters (colour codes and such) using \[...\] as shown in the dupe (and only those characters)

I think it should be PS1='\[\033[1;33m\]\H\[\033[0;35m\]\$\[\033[0;37m\] '

@muru Thanks, maybe this question would be worthwhile to keep around despite there being a similar question? I looked at that one and it doesn't seem to have the double backslashes present, which was my problem? Or should we delete this question?

No, the double backslashes aren't related, they don't affect this. They can be used for extra safety in double-quoted strings "...", but are completely unnecessary in single-quoted strings '...' (which is why I used single quotes - to avoid all that noise from the extra backslashes). There's no need to delete the post.

However, declare -p Foo outputs the contents of Foo in a form suitable for it to be used directly as input to recreate the value. It chooses to double-quote the string, and to escape Backslash and DoubleQuote with another Backslash. So you can initialise variables with single-quotes (or even as ANSI-C quoting), but declare -p prints them differently.
